# Has Isaiah 4:1 been fulfillled?

Tags: isaiah, prophecy

Isaiah 4:1 ESV

> ***4 And seven women shall take hold of one man in that day, saying, “We will eat our own bread and wear our own clothes***, only let us be called by your name; take away our reproach.”

In the above text we learn of seven woman clamoring for one man to marry them yet they will provide for themselves.Im not sure whether this prophecy has been fulfilled or not.

Has this prophecy been fulfilled?

Comment: In order for the competition between women described in this prophecy to be fulfilled, there have to be seven time the number of women than there are men; this type of selective extermination or discriminatory decimation usually happens during wartime (3:25).

Answer (score 3):

**Has Isaiah 4:1 been fulfilled?**

With regard to when this *chapter and verse* was/is to be fulfilled, one can only really argue for the first destruction of Jerusalem and it's temple, by way of the Babylonians led by King Nebuchadnezzar, basically, as there was to be a restoration thereafter. Whereas there was no *qualitative* restoration thereafter after the destruction of Jerusalem and it's second temple in 70 AD. As for the *"End Times"*, one can hardly see the scenario of seven women running after one man at that time, in order to take away their reproach, so that is why I argue for the first scenario.

The book of Isaiah, having been completed in the second half of the 8th Century BC, covers his present time, the then future and then up through the time of Jesus and even contemplates the *"End Times"*. In fact there is an unmistakable *duel prophecy* narrative even within the first 3 chapters, what happened in Isaiah's time and shortly thereafter serving as a preamble, or predestiny, for what happened in 70 AD and for what will happen in the *"End Times"*. It is therefore of *prophetic significance*. **Isaiah 4:1**, which should be taken in conjunction with the first three chapters, involves the then coming apostasy of **Judah and Jerusalem**, as opposed to the **House of Israel**  (made up of the ten northern tribes, soon to be captured by **Assyria**, as a result of their own apostasy). The coming desolation therefore, here being talked about, is with regard to the first destruction of Jerusalem and it's temple, by the **Babylonians** in 607 BC, which resulted in much death, particularly of the male gender (making for the Jewish women's plight) and captivity for many, which was to last for 70 years, **Jer 25:9-12**. Isaiah was to prophesy and warn the Jewish people, of their impending doom, due to their apostasy, even though they would not listen, right up until the Babylonian deportation, **Isaiah 6:11**.

**70 Year Babylonian Captivity**

Although this is a much disputed time frame, we are indeed at least informed as to when the 70 years ended and that was in the first year of Darius the son of Ahasuerus, of Median descent. That year being **538 BC**, **Dan 9:1**, confirmed by Charles Caldwell Ryrie Th.D., Ph.D, himself, in the note section for chapter and verse of "The Ryrie Study Bible, New American Standard Version, 1978 Edition", and many other theologians. One could be excused for thinking, therefore, that the beginning of the captivity must have been 608 BC, although as this time period was to do with the *prophetic*, the 360 day prophetic year would most probably have been   appropriated here, making for a **607 BC** start, which is not, by all accounts, beyond the realm of historical thinking, although many a historian tries to put the destruction of Jerusalem at 587/6 BC, and ignore the fact that the number 70 is not refutable, in fact, the number 70 here has been and still is well attested, with only a handful of detractors to the contrary.

**Branch of the Lord, God**

In **Isaiah 4:2**, Isaiah speaks of restoration. The Hebrew noun rendered *branch* (at least in the NASB), refers to that which springs up, a shoot, a sprout. It is associated with prosperity, increase, and blessings from God [later on this word *branch* would also come to represent the Messiah]. Isaiah thus paints a picture of hope for the future, after the 70 year captivity. Isaiah's words thus assure the people that the land of Judah will be restored to it's former glory and beauty.

**Cyrus the Great**

While Daniel's prayer for the forgiveness and restoration of Jerusalem, as portrayed in the 9th Chapter, was made in 538 BC (the 70th year of Babylonian captivity), it wasn't until the following year that **Cyrus the Great**, now having been anointed by God as the savior of the Jewish people, consented/decreed to their release, for the purposes of rebuilding (the 10 Tribes of Israel, previously mentioned were **NOT** Jewish per se). The Jewish heritage were only 2 Tribes, basically, those of Judah and Benjamin and enjoined by the Levite priesthood, but collectively known as Judah. In 536 BC, Governor Zerubbabel, along with the High Priest Joshua, took 49,897 others back to Jerusalem, whereupon 20 years later the 2nd Jewish temple was completed. It was to take a further two decrees of **Artaxerxes I** to see the completion of the city and it's walls, but that's another story.

Comment: I not only read the context of Isa4, I had to understand it in order to give my answer. At the time of the 2nd Advent, which will lead into Armageddon, more than Jerusalem will be destroyed again but there will not be 7 women chasing every man around in order to have their reproach taken away. I mentioned in my A. that the first 3 chap's were of a duel prophetic nature. You need to reread my explanation of the "branch" and the explanation @Ozzie Ozzie. As for the pillar of smoke and fire in verse 5, that is purely symbolic, and in reference to the "Exodus", emphatic of how God will protect.

Answer (score 1):

A footnote more than an answer - Some answers, example Tony’s, have already outlined a fulfilment of this passage. But there is *more* to understand.

You say … “*Im not sure whether this prophecy has been fulfilled or not.*” - and there is, as said, some. But, you need to understand what prophecy *means*, **not** in our western understanding, but in Hebraic terms - because the Old Testament was written (mostly) by Hebrews, and *for* Hebrews.

Prophecy is not (so much) a ‘prediction’ of some future ‘event’ - prophecy in Hebraic thinking is (a) pattern. A pattern that may have had past fulfilment, so the prophecy will *point* to that event, and foretell it will be repeated, and or will point to possibly multiple future fulfilment’s.

This ‘traps’ many. They ‘see’ a fulfilment of desecration in the temple, then say it’s been fulfilled (so we can now tick it off).

Example …

**MAT 12:40** *For as Jonah was three days and three nights in the belly of the whale, so will the Son of man be three days and three nights in the heart of the earth.*

First, this obviously refers to a past event. But Jesus turns this into a prophecy, which many say  referred to Jesus being resurrected. And yes it does.

But the rabbis *also* know this referred to Lazarus. (Incidentally, that’s why Jesus delayed his coming to Lazarus, in the meantime Lazarus died, and was buried 3 days - this was yet another confirmation [for the disciples] that Jesus would be raised.). But, this actually also points to Revelation 11 - the two witnesses, who are killed, and lay in the street 3 days.)

One prophecy - multiple fulfilment’s. And so it is (will be) for your quoted prophecy from Isaiah.

Comment: I can't argue with what you are saying here. *"Dual"* prophecy is rife within the Bible and is the case here, 70 AD a definite case in point. But the verse in question needs to be put into it's *initial* specific time frame, which is what I endeavored to do and is what the OP, I think, is looking for.

Comment: @OldeEnglish No argument from me. You answered the OP correctly. Prophecy should *always* be first interpreted by its present ‘relevant’ context - always. As I tried to make clear, I was *only* adding commentary - not answering. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That Day is reference to The Lords Day.
Revelation 20.  It has not come to pass yet. When the 7th Trump sets off.

> Isaiah 4:1 "And in the day seven women shall take hold of one man, saying, "We will eat our own bread, and wear our own apparel: only let us be called by thy name, to take away our reproach."

> Isaiah 4:2 "In that day shall
> the Branch of the Lord be beautiful and glorious, and the fruit of the earth shall be excellent and comely for them that are escaped of Israel."

The "Branch" of the Lord is Jesus Christ.
Those that "escaped of Israel" are those that escape the confusion that Satan's deceptions bring upon the earth. That confusion is the "Babylon" of the end times. You only escape by knowing the truth from God's Word .

---

Source
https://www.youtube.com/user/TheShepherdsChapel/playlists

https://www.youtube.com/user/JustThoughtsstudies/playlists

Comment: I partially agree with you in the sense that it is future, the verse you mention "them who escaped' I believe relates to the great tribulation when Jerusalem is taken into captivity and God's people flee, its when the man of sin sets his throne in the Holy land and has made war on God's people. It's written in multiple places. It sets the stage for the second exodus when God gathers His children from out of captivity with a mighty hand. – FYI: that wasn't me that down-voted you, I would always put a reason if I down voted someone - otherwise its a bit spineless : )

Comment: @0000 no worries. down votes or up votes are totally out of my power to predict.  As long as I get a upvote from God and Yeshua thats all that matters to me. Ill be careful in that regard. Wish i could explain more but the resource links i offered will go into greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

**Has Isaiah 4:1 been fulfilled?**

Has this prophecy been fulfilled?  Yes, with the fall of Jerusalem to the Babylonians. Wars obviously created a severe shortage of marriageable men, so women took hold of a man to have his name and so be married, being married took their reproach away.

A husband legally had to provide food, clothing, and shelter for his wives,  these women were willing to release their husband to be from such an obligation.

Comment: 0000  Thks for your comment, I looked up the scriptures, I  agree with with the footnotes on the NET Bible Isaiah 4:2,  It has nothing to do  with the millenial kingdom.  In Vs2 God assures the Israelites that the land od Judah will be restored to its former Glory,  NET Bible 4:2 states  "At that time the crops given by the Lord will bring admiration and honor;   the produce of the land will be a source of pride and delight to those who remain in Israel." I suggest you read the footnotes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I think the spiritual fulfillment is about the 7 churches in Revelation. A woman generally symbolizes a church, like the bride of Christ being the church.

Bread is symbolic of like...doctrine, knowledge,beliefs. ( So breaking bread depicts opening up knowledge so that you can consume, digest, take it into you)

Clothing depicts what you're covered by..you can be clothed with Christ's  righteousness or filthy dirty rags of sin.

So I'd say having their own bread and clothing is not good. It would be speaking of relying on their own beliefs and not being clothed in Christ's raiment.

Revelation
1:4 John to the **seven churches** which are in Asia: Grace be unto you, and peace, from him which is, and which was, and which is to come; and from the seven Spirits which are before his throne

Answer (score 0):

The historical Jewish interpretation is indeed written from a Jewish perspective. Here, it refers to a likely common hypothetical about what happens in a historical context to cultures that loose an important battle. Most of the men would be killed leaving those who are left the responsibility of replenishing the population of that culture, this means that the few men would likely do their part given the difference between the female and male populations.

However, there remains a further question about the context. Assuming that there is what many would call a spiritual context, not merely a context rooted in particular events, we could argue that there is a broader context to understand this particular passage. This interpretation would rest on the hypothetical somewhat, but be applicable not only in the historical setting when cultures where largely defined geographically. We could broaden the context to not only include historical communities, but present and future as well. Of course there is a concern here about turning the description of an event into something like a law, but one that rests on human psychology. When faced with the extinction of one's culture, is there a tendency to engage in more sexually risky practices such as the sharing of romantic partners would likely entail?

If it is possible to broaden the context in this way, it would give us a new way to look at emerging relationship trends in our own day. For instance, it may change the ways in which we explain declining marriage duration, less formal child rearing practices, for instance the lack of a marriage contract articulating the grounds for which new human lives would be brought into the world and cared for, etc.

This interpretation of Isaiah 4:1 is risky however. One potential worry is that we often attribute changing relationship practices to a culture's success and not as evidence of it declining. For instance, consider Scandinavian countries. I think that its important here to distinguish between declining birthrates in conjunction with changes in relationship practices versus lack of changes in birthrates and changes in relationship practices. We might be justified in believing that the warning in Isaiah 4:1 is to a culture where the birthrates are remaining the same or growing while there is a change in relationship practices, an important implication where the care and concern for new human lives is concerned given that all research attributes a positive correlation between child well-being outcomes and two parent homes. But it's hard to know what the birthrate would be for the culture referenced in Isaiah and as such, its not clear what contemporary society this warning could be applied to.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posing this question. It provides context for something that has niggled about Matthew's parable of the ten virgins, since this parable is given in context of the end time's impact specifically on Israel, and the description of the virgins being neither the bride nor bridegroom, but members of the wedding party. John the Baptist describes himself in stating that the friend of the bridegroom rejoices with the bridegroom. In mainstream Christian doctrine today, this parable is applied to the church, and indeed, it is an apt warning, but is the largely gentile bride of present times really the direct intended object?Add to this the prophecy of the 144,000 sealed "virgins" from Revelations 7 and 14. How one proceeds from here would depend on how one views end time prophecy, and whether one believes that Jesus comes for his bride before the full chaos of the tribulation. I subscribe to that position, which also seems to qualify as the time of Jacob's trouble. I cannot be dogmatic, and would appreciate thoughts on overlaying Isaiah's prophecy with this parable and the 144,000. Jesus told the Samaritan woman that he could give her springs of living water. The church was given the gift of the permanent indwelling of the Holy Spirit. Oil is often a symbol of the Holy Spirit. Five of the virgins have ample oil, the springs of living waters, and are able to light the way for the wedding party. The five virgins are left with neither the light from their own insufficient supply (might we call this the witness of OT prophecy compared to the NT revelation of the new covenant?), nor the departed light of those who had both the supply of the OT and the indwelling of the Holy Spirit. The five who are left realize their lack, and must now provide for themselves (food and clothing) that they could have been enjoying without cost. They now realize their obvious error and desire to be called by the name of Christ, and have spiritual children. They are forced to grope their way through the Messianic prophecies on their own: find their way to those who sell oil. Contrast the experiences of the disciples on the road to Emmaus, the Ethiopian eunuch, and the apostle Paul. The two disciples continued in confusion until Jesus "opened" the Scriptures to them. The eunuch asked Philip how he could understand the prophecy of Isaiah unless someone explained it to him, which Philip did. Paul had to get knocked off his horse and struck blind-- and eventually martyred. In the parable, the five virgins find themselves shut out from the wedding feast. Rather than eternal damnation, this might mean the extreme temporal woes of the tribulation, which leads to many being martyred, as Paul, who refuse the mark of the beast.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/50728)

Answer (score 0):

Read the rest of the chapter. Understand the key phrase "in that day." Often, real-life occurrences point to a separate time in the future (What will be occurring again in Yerushalayim at the end of days?) or at happenings at a different level. Where does the rest of the chapter point to? Also, look at Mt. 7:21-23. In Rev. it speaks of the seven congregations. The seven women are indicated in the seven congregations (Torah observant groups). If one looks at Is. 4:1, there are several clues. The making of one's own food represents them making up their own teachings. In wearing their own clothes, it represents them having their own righteousness (doing what was right in their own eyes).

What happened in the time spoken directly of in Ch. 3 will occur again physically. It will occur at the same time that Eze. 16:63 will occur, as well.

There are quite a few ways to look at many passages in Scripture. Knowing their varied applications helps us see (intellectual perception).

To cut a long story short, Is. 4:1 indicates a time that was soon to happen in Israel. It is also an indicator of what will happen again. Do an eschatological study regarding Israel, and you'll see. That is the physical. Verses 2-6 indicate the end times, which have yet to happen. Pointing right back to the Messiah, when He said, "In that day" in Mt. 7, we see that same period of time at the end.

Things of the past occur for different reasons. The first is to carry out the justice of the Creator. Second, things happen to point us to a future time. Verse 4:1 is the intermediate connection between what was shortly about to happen and what will happen again at the end of time. It has a dual application, tying what has happened (ch. 3) with what will happen again (4:2-6). What will happen again will create a much better result.

There is no "over-spiritualization" in this. People who claim that do not have the ability to see beyond the physical.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.